# Get object by attribute in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The following line works fine in IE9 but is giving me a 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error in IE8.

```
var id = $("td[title='Project Documents']");
```

Is there an IE8 compatible way to get an object based on a specific attribute?

Comment: Try using rel instead of title. Not 100% if it's going to work, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Where does the error stem from?

Comment: that line of code you've quoted looks like jQuery -- if so, it should work exactly as is in all browsers. This may be the line where you're getting an error, but it isn't the cause of the error. Are you loading jQuery properly? Is the code being executed before jQuery is loaded? There's a bunch of other questions I could ask, but I think we need to establish a bit more about your code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) what you have should work. Try this:

```
$("td[title]").filter(function () {
    return 'Project Documents' === $(this).attr('title');
});
```

It could be that the capitalization or whitespace chars do not match exactly.

Comment: @user1783422 Nice. Also if you change `td[title]` to just `td` so the filter runs on all `td`'s it would work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to test this on a title without any whitespace in the title to test to see if it is actually this causing the problem.